# Access serial monitor on linux cli? Using arduino-cli?

Tags: serial, arduino-cli

I have an arduino uno connected via USB to a raspberry pi, the raspi is accessible via ssh only.

Just started a bit with arduino-cli ; I upload a sketch which reads my analog pins. How can I access the serial monitor to get the data??

Comment: I'm trying to upload a program for serial communication with 9600 Br with 1sec delay.
but this error is avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding what should I do?

Comment: @user137442, Welcome! Placing a question in the comments section under an existing one, will probably not get your question answered. Please consider [asking a separate question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) once you've made sure your question has not been answered elsewhere on Arduino Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 13):

Programs such as `screen`, `minicom` or (my favorite)
[`picocom`](https://github.com/npat-efault/picocom) are useful if you want bidirectional communication
between the Arduino and the host computer. If you only want to *read*
what the Arduino sends, that can be done with `cat`:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 raw 115200
cat /dev/ttyACM0
```

Answer (score 8):

I use `minicom`.

```
$ sudo apt-get install minicom
... blah blah blah ...
$ minicom -D /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200
```

Minicom can take a bit of getting used to. Use `CTRL-A` to initiate a command sequence. `CTRL-A X` is exit. `CTRL-A O` is configuration ("*O*ptions") where you can configure flow control and such.

Many people also use `screen` to do the same job, but I like the interface that `minicom` gives - it's more terminal-like.

Comment: thx! Forgot about that, I knew it and also screen. Obviously did a bad job at web search on the topic :P

Comment: And how do you send "Hi Arduino" to the Arduino board?

Comment: @user171780 With minicom? Just type it when connected. With screen? Just type it when connected. From the command line? `echo "Hi Arduino" > /dev/ttyACM0`

Comment: If I type and hit enter, nothing happens. I only see whatever Arduino sent (after reset) but he is not listening to me (so no answer either).

Comment: @user171780 Unless you have programmed your Arduino to echo back what it receives you won't see anything. Without knowing what your code is I cannot help you.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the problem that arduino-cli includes no serial monitor. I tried out screen, minicom and other but they are a bit difficult to get used with them. So I created a small python script which works as an serial monitor in the command line:
https://github.com/PBahner/Serial-Monitor