# Constantly Stream data vía Bluetooth to monitoring

Tags: arduino-nano, python, hc-05, data, stream

I am using a Bluetooth module HC-05 to Stream data from Arduino to My computer. In they computer I am using a python script to receive

They specifications:
Baud rate: 9600

But I am getting an error. The right data got in the computer should be:

b'123.098x726.8393x123x\r\n'

Which I almost always get, but sometimes I get the following:

b'123.098x726.8393x123x123.098x726.8393x123\r\n'. **wrong**

So I don't know happens, in python I use the method reset_input_buffer() and reset_output_buffer() and in Arduino ide I use Serial.flush()

The error keep happens, would it be the baudrate? I increase it would it be the solutionn?

Thanks in advance

```
String str;
String strs[8];

int pwm=9;

int tech;
String sync_fromApp = "?";
String sync_ok = "okx";

int cyc_num;
int PWM_0;
int PWM_i;
int PWM_f;

float volt;
float cur;
int t;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  TCCR1B = TCCR1B & B11111000 | B00000001;
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setTimeout(5);
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
  pinMode(pwm, OUTPUT);
  analogWrite(pwm, 130);
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int strCount = 0;
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    
    str = Serial.readString();
    str.trim();
    
    if (str == sync_fromApp) {
      Serial.println(sync_ok);
      //Serial.flush();
    }

    while (str.length() > 0) {
      int index = str.indexOf('x');
      if (index == -1) {
        strs[strCount++] = str;
        break;
      }
      else {
        strs[strCount++] = str.substring(0, index);
        str = str.substring(index + 1);
      }
    }

    tech = strs[0].toInt();
    float E0 = strs[1].toInt() / 1000.0;
    float Ei = strs[2].toInt() / 1000.0;
    float Ef = strs[3].toInt() / 1000.0;
    cyc_num = strs[4].toInt();
    int scan_rate = strs[5].toInt();
    int t_chro = strs[6].toInt();
    int t_step_chro = strs[7].toInt();
    float e00 = ((995.0 / 1986.0) * 5.06 + (995.0 / 1004.0) * E0);
    PWM_0 = e00 * (255 / 4.99); //Starting Voltage
    float eii = ((995.0 / 1986.0) * 5.06 + (995.0 / 1004.0) * Ei);
    PWM_i = eii * (255 / 4.99)-1; //Min Voltage
    float eff = ((995.0 / 1986.0) * 5.06 + (995.0 / 1004.0) * Ef);
    PWM_f = eff * (255 / 4.99)+1; //Max Voltage
    long t = (4990000L) / (256L * scan_rate); //delay scan rate
    //default:
    analogWrite(pwm, PWM_0);
    switch (tech) {
      //---Cyclic voltammetry---
      case 1:
        delay(3000);
        for (int n = 1; n <= cyc_num; n++) {
          for (int val = PWM_0; val < PWM_f; val++) {
            analogWrite(pwm, val);

            volt = 0.01974563 * val - 2.558; //0.01974563
            cur = 0.51469 * (analogRead(A0)) - 255.226; //254.226

            Serial.print(volt, 3);
            Serial.print('x');
            Serial.print(cur, 3);
            Serial.print('x');
            Serial.print(val);
            Serial.println('x');
            Serial.flush();
            delay(t);
          }

          for (int val = PWM_f; val > PWM_i; val--) {
            analogWrite(pwm, val);

            volt = 0.01974563 * val - 2.558;
            cur = 0.50669 * (analogRead(A0)) - 255.226;
            //cur_ave = analogRead(A0);
            Serial.print(volt, 3);
            Serial.print('x');
            Serial.print(cur, 3);
            Serial.print('x');
            Serial.print(val);
            Serial.println('x');
            Serial.flush();
            delay(t);
          }
          PWM_0 = PWM_i;
          //Serial.println(n);
        }
        Serial.println("Nx");
        Serial.flush();
        analogWrite(pwm, 130);
        tech = 0;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    delay(200);
  }
}
```

Above left the arduino sketch.

Below is the python code

```python
            self.ser.write(self.parametersToArduino.encode()) #command to start stream
            pass
        
        self.ser.reset_input_buffer()   #flush input buffer
        self.ser.reset_output_buffer()   #flush output buffer    
        COM.stop_button["state"] = "active"

        while self.threading:
            try:
                data.RowMsg = self.ser.readline()  # read data from arduino
                data.DecodeMsg()                   #decode data from arduino
                if len(data.RowMsg)>0:
                    if b'N' in data.RowMsg:
                        #print("It's over")

                        self.threading = False
                        break
                    data.upXData()  #update a list to plot
                    data.upYData()  #update a list to plot
                    self.ser.reset_input_buffer()
                    self.ser.reset_output_buffer()
                    pass
                pass
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                pass
```

DecodeMsg is the code below

```python
    def DecodeMsg(self):
        temporal = self.RowMsg.decode('utf8')
        if len(temporal)>0:
            if "x" in temporal:
                self.msg = temporal.split("x")
                del self.msg[-1]
                pass
            print(self.msg) #debugg
            pass
        pass
```

Comment: The problem could be on the Python side. Do you have some other means of monitoring that serial stream? The Arduino serial monitor, PuTTY, [picocom, or even cat](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/79058/7508)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I use serial monitor of Arduino IDE as well but I still got the error. It is like if the next data of the stream was send at the same time that the previous data

Comment: Do you still have the same error if you remove the Bluetooth module and run the serial flow through USB? If this is the case, it could be a bug in the Arduino sketch, and we may be able to help finding it if you share the code.

Comment: I haven't still tested with USB. I could test, but let me upload My Arduino sketch.

Comment: Ready, the Sketch is already uploaded, thanks.

Comment: reduce your code to continually sending `b'123.098x726.8393x123x\r\n`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, what do You mean? You suggest that I delete the other operations? And My code is only with lines of Serial.print()?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're doing. In particular what input you're feeding this code. What I notice is that there doesn't seem to be much keeping `strCount` from overflowing `strs`

Comment: The behavior of input works fine, the problem is the output.

Comment: Post the python code.

Comment: Of course, let me post it

Comment: Update: I have uploaded the python code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this an answer, but it is easy to implement and may help you figure out what is going on.

I don't think it is a baud rate problem because the characters appear to be intact, but some are missing. I think it is a serial buffer overflow resulting in a mix of old and new characters.

To test this out, I would insert a counter into the beginning of the "packet" being sent. My suspicion is that when you see the error, you will be able to see that one packet is being messed up when it overflows. So, you might get something like this (where the first 3 digits are the packet number):

b'**001**123.098x726.8393x123x\r\n'
b'**001**123.098x726.8393x123x123.098x726.8393x123\r\n
b'**003**123.098x726.8393x123x\r\n'

It may not be definitive, but might help to more clearly see what is happening.

Before doing this, I would probably comment out:
TCCR1B = TCCR1B & B11111000 | B00000001;
which is increasing the PWM frequency on 9. That, just to see if this changes the behavior since it is so easy to test out.

Hope it helps, but I admit that it is just a suggestion.

BTW: interesting problem and I hope you will tell us what happens.